# Play mp3 files saved in the /res or /raw folder on Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How can I play mp3 files with Phonegap saved in the /res or /raw folder on Android?

Because this

```
src= 'android.resource://this.is.my.package/raw/bap.mp3';
```

Is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f = new File(sdcard, "/your custom directory");
```

Try this. Tugrul.